# I'm trying to fill an ArrayList with Objects

Tags: arraylist

I'm trying to fill an ArrayList with Objects that contain integers and convert that into an Array of Objects, where, from there I can determine the highest integer value in my Array of Objects. But for some reason by the time I have reached the point where I can compare values against eachother, I have lost half of my ArrayList or Array of Objects.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
public class Exercise11_04
{
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {
       System.out.println("Enter a sequence of integers ending in 0: \n");
       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);  
       ArrayList<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

       while(input.nextInt() != 0)
       {
           intList.add(new Integer(input.nextInt()));
       }//end filler loop
       System.out.println(max(intList));
       arrayContents(intList);
   } 

   public static Integer max(ArrayList<Integer> list)
   {
       int maxIntIndex = 0;

       Integer[] integers = new Integer[list.size()];
       integers = list.toArray(integers);
       for(int index = 0; index < integers.length; index++ )
       {
           if(integers[index].getValue() >= integers[maxIntIndex].getValue()  )
           {
               maxIntIndex = index;
           }
       }
       return integers[maxIntIndex];
   }
   class Integer
   {
       private  int integer;

       Integer() {this(0);}
       Integer(int integer) {this.integer = integer;}
       public int getValue() {return this.integer;}
       public String toString()
       {
           return "The max value is: " + getValue();
       }//
}//end
```

I tried to check to see the values of the array with this method

```
public static void arrayContents(ArrayList<Integer> list)
{
    Integer[] integers = new Integer[list.size()];
    integers = list.toArray(integers); 
    for(int index = 0; index < integers.length; index++)
    {
        System.out.println("The index is: " + index + " .The value is: " + integers[index].getValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to use a debugger?

Comment: is your code compiling accessing non static class from static method? Its not clear what do you mean by lost half of my list or array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `input.nextInt()` twice per iteration in first loop; once to test if the value is zero, and once to add to you list. Consequently, half the values are compared against 0, and the other half are added to the list.

Just read once:

```
int v;
while ( (v = input.nextInt) != 0)
    intList.add(v);
```

Comment: But I still had to add the object so it was
       intList.add(new Integer(v));

Comment: Unless you are using a very old version of Java (1.4 or older), you don't need to create an `Integer` when adding an `int` to a container; Java will do that for you (it's called autoboxing).